# Pushing info from a private git server to a service like gitlab

Tags: git, repository, git-remote

I have been contemplating getting a Bitscope Raspberry Pi Blade Server for a while and wanted to install `git-core` onto it. I was wondering if there is a way to take the local repository and commit the changes to that repository to a service provider like gitlab. I am wondering this because I'd like to have a complete off site version of all of the code. Is this possible?

Comment: So you're looking to 'synchronise' the repository from your local server to gitlab.com?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options for this as below.

---

### Two remotes locally

You can add two remotes locally

```
git remote add blade https://example.com/user/repo.git
git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

(presuming you've not added any remotes already - if you have just add the one that is missing).

then you can execute

```
git push blade {branch-name}
git push gitlab {branch-name}
```

when you want to push to the two separate remotes respectively.

---

### Extra remote on your blade server

To add a remote you can run:

```
git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

then you can execute

```
git push gitlab {branch-name}
```

to push to gitlab